# Plotting a 3D graph from explicit equation

Tags: vector-spaces, graphing-functions, 3d

I´m a 2nd year engineering student and today we learned how to plot 3d graphs from a $XYZ$ equation on paper.

For example, I know ($\frac{X^2}{9}+ \frac{Y^2}{16} + \frac{Z^2}{9} =1$) will produce an ellipsoid. I  understand very well how to get the traces (XY XZ YZ planes) individually, and how to plot it.

However, I´m a little confused on how to do this on software, since most of the stuff available online assumes your input function will be either parametric or cartesian, in the form $Z = aX^2 + bY^2...$ but there is no option to put a power on the z variable anywhere.

Given that what I have is an equation (not a function), how would you translate such format (equation) so plotting software will understand its syntax?

Comment: This will vary depending on what software you are using. Can you elaborate on what software you are using and whether it is required by your course or if you are interested in learning about different programs which would help you with implicit 3D graphing.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve for $Z$ to get two solutions,
$$Z=\sqrt{9\Bigl(1-\frac{X^2}9-\frac{Y^2}{16}\Bigr)}\quad\hbox{or}\quad
  Z=-\sqrt{9\Bigl(1-\frac{X^2}9-\frac{Y^2}{16}\Bigr)}$$
and then plot each part separately.  IMHO a better option would be to obtain some different software :)  For example, Maple will quite happily accept your original equation and give you a nice 3D plot.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha does this very easily, for example:

[`ContourPlot3D[x y^2 + 3 x^2 z + z^3 y == 1, {x,-3,3}, {y,-3,3}, {z,-3,3}]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot3D%5Bx%20y%5E2%20%2B%203%20x%5E2%20z%20%2B%20z%5E3%20y%20%3D%3D%201,%20%7Bx,-3,3%7D,%20%7By,-3,3%7D,%20%7Bz,-3,3%7D%5D)

gives a rather nice picture.